# how to get any parameter value from the route which have special character # in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have following route in angular route:

```
http://localhost:9000/login#id=54119212faf7d1ec159f9781&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NDExOTIxMmZhZjdkMWVjMTU5Zjk3ODEiLCJpYXQiOjE0MTA0Mzc2NTA3MTcsImV4cCI6MTQxMDQ1NTY1MDcxN30.x3G_faxsnzbyZWSRMNNpc2qFjHI6kBTca_Q9jwnWRHQ
```

how can i access id parameter from this route. note here # is not ?. 
if there were ? then i can get it through `$location.search()`
please suggest me if you have any good approach

Comment: You'll have to parse `window.location.hash`, or I guess `$location.hash()`

Comment: is there a reason you cant use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: @JaredReeves I don't think `$routeParams` loads the **hash**; it just loads the location's **search** and **path**

Comment: dumb question but why would you format url like that in the first place? Angular routing params would take care of `id=` and with better structure could take advantage of `$location.search()`

Answer (score -1):

Use $location to grab the url and do string manipulation on that. This is roughly what you need (I am unsure if you need to account for the #). $location.search() will not work because there is no "?" in the url:

```
var url = $location.url();

//check if id is present in url    
if(url.indexOf('id') != -1)
{
  //extract value from url
  var id = url.replace('/id=', '');
}
```

And in response to @charlietfl question (I don't have enough points to comment), I've used this before when using a API's Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication (Instagram in my case), where my redirect URL contained an access token.